# How to make sure what is causing slow boot time on Lubuntu?

Tags: boot, lubuntu

I'm not sure what counts slow or fast boot in the Linux world, but it seems like the Lubuntu machine that I have here ([specs here](http://www.cnet.com/products/hp-compaq-business-desktop-dc7800-p-e2160-1-8-ghz-monitor-none-series/specs/)), seems to be booting somewhat slow (around 50 seconds). My parents started complaining to me about slow boot and I thought I'll look into it.

The LXSession configuration wizard did not show anything that should slow the boot down. It showed the following services will start when computer is starting (computer is not in English, so I'm not sure if I'm translating correctly): power management, software updater, networking service, Screen Locker, user folder updates, AT-SPI D-Bus Bus.

Then I looked into `dmesg`, I suppose it's showing the boot time in the beginning of the line and saw some strange behaviours:

```
[   21.827368] audit: type=1400 audit(1471992144.548:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=1854 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.944457] audit: type=1400 audit(1471992144.668:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=1850 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.944478] audit: type=1400 audit(1471992144.668:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper" pid=1850 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   32.425176] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   32.892255] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   34.236909] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   34.237022] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[   34.237060] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
[   42.868183] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[   42.868192] ata1: EH complete
```

So for some reason on the 21st second it just hangs and starts loading IPv6 service that I have nothing to do with. Could it be the reason behind slow boot? And if yes, how could I troubleshoot it?

I've been googling around for some time, but haven't really found good advice that would help me. The things I've tried haven't resolved the issue.

I'd be grateful if someone would help me investigate what's causing slow boot on this Lubuntu machine.

Thanks!

edit: A user called [eridani](https://askubuntu.com/users/251621/eridani) suggested me to take a look in a tool called [systemd-analyze](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Maximizing_performance/Boot_process#Using_systemd-analyze), which may help me discover what slows down the boot time.
Here's the output of a command `systemd-analyze plot > ~/Desktop/systemd.html`: [link to download](https://mega.nz/#!FV1iHRoK!t5z6ehCSy8dMcyAnodGsSuZHeaLT6A9qFNWPZY24G8s) (couldn't find a better way to share it).

Another command that was suggested in the Arch Linux blog was `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and here's the output of it:

```
~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @38.425s
└─multi-user.target @38.425s
  └─teamviewerd.service @36.611s +1.812s (displayed in red color)
    └─network-online.target @36.598s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @24.297s +12.301s (displayed in red color)
        └─NetworkManager.service @19.493s +4.785s (displayed in red color)
          └─dbus.service @15.022s
            └─basic.target @14.901s
              └─paths.target @14.901s
                └─systemd-networkd-resolvconf-update.path @14.901s
                  └─sysinit.target @14.869s
                    └─apparmor.service @6.651s +8.167s (displayed in red color)
                      └─local-fs.target @6.646s
                        └─run-user-1000.mount @34.907s
                          └─local-fs-pre.target @6.646s
                            └─systemd-remount-fs.service @6.533s +100ms (displayed in red color)
                              └─system.slice @1.934s
                                └─-.slice @1.851s
```

NetworkManager and apparmor.service seem to take quite a bit to load. Could I tweak something so that these would load faster?

Then again, is 44 seconds a good boot-up time given my specs? Could I somehow get it down a bit, using some even more lightweight distro (then again, I don't want to lose that much usability too, given it's my parents' computer, current Lubuntu GUI is good enough, I may try Xubuntu too).

Thanks for the help.

**edit2:** Apparently the `disable` command did not actually disable the `NetworkManager-wait-online.service`, so I used the following commands:

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service  
systemctl mask NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

And got the system boot time from this: `Startup finished in 5.647s (kernel) + 38.452s (userspace) = 44.100s` to this: `Startup finished in 5.487s (kernel) + 26.994s (userspace) = 32.481s`. Though from a psychological perspective, it doesn't seem like, it's 12 seconds faster, but if the numbers say so, then I've got nothing to argue.

And now we have the `apparmor.service` left, which takes ~10 seconds to load. Here's the updated command of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @26.958s
└─multi-user.target @26.958s
  └─ntp.service @26.590s +368ms (displayed in red)
    └─network-online.target @26.569s
      └─network.target @26.569s
        └─NetworkManager.service @23.537s +3.032s (displayed in red)
          └─dbus.service @16.973s
            └─basic.target @16.896s
              └─sockets.target @16.896s
                └─pcscd.socket @16.896s
                  └─sysinit.target @16.895s
                    └─apparmor.service @6.518s +10.348s (displayed in red)
                      └─local-fs.target @6.513s
                        └─local-fs-pre.target @6.456s
                          └─systemd-remount-fs.service @6.353s +88ms (displayed in red)
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @1.901s
                              └─-.mount @1.826s
                                └─system.slice @1.901s
                                  └─-.slice @1.826s
```

And the output of `systemd-analyze blame | head`:

```
:~$ systemd-analyze blame | head
         10.348s apparmor.service
          9.634s dev-sda1.device
          7.510s ModemManager.service
          7.449s grub-common.service
          6.908s networking.service
          6.898s apport.service
          6.879s irqbalance.service
          6.791s systemd-logind.service
          6.724s ondemand.service
          6.595s alsa-restore.service
```

Helpful user, [eridani](https://askubuntu.com/users/251621/eridani), asked for output of two commands, which might help me troubleshoot the slowness of apparmor.service and here they are:

```
~$ systemctl status apparmor
● apparmor.service - LSB: AppArmor initialization
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apparmor; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since P 2016-08-28 20:00:10 EEST; 31min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 785 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apparmor start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

    aug   28 19:59:59 dc7800 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: AppArmor initialization...
    aug   28 20:00:08 dc7800 apparmor[785]:  * Starting AppArmor profiles
    aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 apparmor[785]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
    aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 apparmor[785]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
    aug   28 20:00:10 dc7800 apparmor[785]:    ...done.
    aug   28 20:00:10 dc7800 systemd[1]: Started LSB: AppArmor initialization.
```

And another one:

```
:~$ journalctl |grep apparmor
aug   28 20:00:08 dc7800 apparmor[785]:  * Starting AppArmor profiles
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 audit[1849]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1849 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 audit[1849]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1849 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 audit[1849]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=1849 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 audit[1849]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1849 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1472403609.772:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1849 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1472403609.772:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1849 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1472403609.772:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=1849 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1472403609.772:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1849 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 audit[1848]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=1848 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 audit[1848]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=1848 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 apparmor[785]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1472403609.852:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=1848 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1472403609.852:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=1848 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 audit[1852]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ntpd" pid=1852 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 apparmor[785]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1472403609.920:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ntpd" pid=1852 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:09 dc7800 audit[1854]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=1854 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:10 dc7800 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1472403609.996:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=1854 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:10 dc7800 audit[1850]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=1850 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:10 dc7800 audit[1850]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper" pid=1850 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:10 dc7800 audit[1850]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer" pid=1850 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:10 dc7800 audit[1850]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer//sanitized_helper" pid=1850 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:10 dc7800 audit[1850]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" pid=1850 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:10 dc7800 audit[1850]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer//sanitized_helper" pid=1850 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:10 dc7800 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1472403610.068:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=1850 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:10 dc7800 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1472403610.072:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper" pid=1850 comm="apparmor_parser"
aug   28 20:00:10 dc7800 apparmor[785]:    ...done.
```

I'm trying to Google too in the meantime, but I'd appreciate good thoughts from here too :) Thanks for all the help, especially [eridani](https://askubuntu.com/users/251621/eridani)!

Comment: You have 2 small jumps there at second 21 and then again at s34. Yo can better understand what is happening if you run `sytemd-analyze plot > Desktop/systemd.html` then open the file in your browser.

Comment: I updated the original post with outputs from `systemd-analyze`.

Comment: Those 2 are often causing trouble. You can reduce the time threshold for network one or plainly disable it at boot most users report no side effects after doing it so let's disable it on boot leaving it available on demand `systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service`. For apparmor which should be handled with care for security you can run `systemctl status apparmor` and `journalctl |grep apparmor` to get more info on what it is doing and see if anyone knows something.

Comment: I got the boot time slightly better and now inspecting the apparmor service and it's slowness. See updated original post in the section "edit2".

Comment: Glad it worked, I dare to say that 32s for your system may be pretty acceptable. Keep in mind that `systemctl mask` renders the service totally unavailable to systemd. On the other hand `disable` prevents the service from starting automatically but leave it available if required later. However, if you don't notice any problem *masked* is OK. Idk about Apparmor, but you can save 7s by disabling ModemManager.service if you don't have a 3G, 4G, UMTS connection or connect to internet through Bluetooth tethering. Then you may get NetworkManager warnings on system log but are safe to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Well to put a couple things in perspective, I have a relatively fast system (using Ubuntu) and it boots in around 8 seconds (i7 @ 3.6GHz, 16GB Ram @ 1866MHz, and a M.2 drive housing the root partition).

The desktop specs look relatively low (1.8 GHz, 1 GB Ram installed @ 667MHz, and a slower than average HDD at 3GBps). You aren't going to get fantastic loading times with this system. Now lubuntu is more lightweight than Ubuntu, so it should help, but you still have quite a bit loading at the startup.

From inspection, looks like your ram could be a bottleneck, that with the speed of your HDD. I'm imagining that your HDD access indicator is flashing a lot at T: 21sec?

You seem to think it hasn't always been this slow though. The more services you add, the slower the load times. Especially, also, if your HDD is full, it will take more time to seek and find the information.

Although this doesn't really solve your problem, it helped put it in perspective and shows some potential issues at your loading times.

Comment: Well, I've been trying out different distros on this machine, like Mint, Ubuntu and Debian. My parents said that it's been faster before, but then said that it got slower over time. Then I thought I'd try Lubuntu, given it's advertised as so lightweight that you could install it on any computer and it'd still be fast. And to be honest, it does quite hang and give me black screen on startup, it's probably loading some services or something like that. And yeah, the specs aren't amazing, but a user here suggested to look into a tool called `systemd-analyze`, so I'll provide the results there.